# App engine billing does not make much sense

Tags: python, google-app-engine, billing

The instances graph shows me a max of 5 instances at the start of my billing day:

[image]

But my instance settings are as follows:

```
instance_class: B2
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 2
```

Have no clue how the number of instances was increased to 5. Even if its a B2 instance which is counted twice for each, it should be a max of 4 instances.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, deploy a new version of your app to app-engine? Sometimes it happens that the old version still has instances and the new one too. That could explain why you have more than the configured instances for a short duration.

Comment: nope, didnt update the version or anything

Comment: is that a view of a module / version or all modules ?